# how to pass parameter in custom command in Gocd tool?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to use go cd  for continuous delivery and create a pipeline for the same. I m able to get success result after running the job but in that job i did not pass any parameter.I  want to pass parameter in custom command to reduce repetition within my configurations.

Comment: Please add a link to `go cd` and a code example of what you have and want to achieve.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @joel goldstick  I am using Go CD UI for making my pipeline parameterized .

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the clear picture of what you are expecting. But as far as I could understand, you want to perform a `custom command` task by passing few parameters as input.

When you choose custom command, you will get something like

[image]

In `Arguments` block, you could give the `input parameters` you need to pass for that particular task.

**Edit : I think this may help you.**

[Parameterize your Configuration](https://docs.go.cd/current/configuration/admin_use_parameters_in_configuration.html)

Please go through this link and see whether this helps you. They had explained about defining and using the parameter in a pipeline

Comment: !!  As we have a parameter option in Jenkins and we would be able to pass parameter in that but the same thing I am not able to achieve  from Go CD..Hope you understand my concern.

Comment: As we have a parameter option in Jenkins and we would be able to pass parameter in that but the same thing I am not able to achieve  from Go CD..Hope you understand my concern.

Comment: @user3675569, Please look at the edited answer and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

[image] We can pass parameter via a environment variable -eg If you want to pass a version in your custom command and value is 1.2.4 so define the value in environment variable and pass the value in your command for example ./abc #{version}.

You might get error while editing the command (Parameter  is not defined error) add the same varibale in parameter tab as well .[![enter image description here][2]][2]